# View content of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

How to view the content of `NSMutableDictionary`?

Answer (score 6):

Just print contents in console:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [yourDict description]);
```

To iterate through dictionary elements:

```
for (id key in [yourDict allKeys]){
   id obj = [yourDict objectForKey: key];
   // Do something with them
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"yourMutableDictionary - %@",yourMutableDictionary);
```