# convert NSDictionary to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am trying to put the content of an NSDictionary into an NSString for testing, But have no idea how to achieve this. Is it possible? if so how would one do such a thing?

The reason I am doing this, Is I need to check the content of a NSDicitonary without the debugger running on my device. as I have to delete the running app from multitasking bar of the ios so I can see if the values I am saving into the dictionary are still available afterwards.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424439/view-contents-of-nsmutabledictionary

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can call [aDictionary description], or anywhere you would need a format string, just use %@ to stand in for the dictionary:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my dictionary is %@", aDictionary];
```

or

```
NSLog(@"My dictionary is %@", aDictionary);
```

Comment: ahh.. cool, yea I know how to log it but did not know you could do that to get it into an nsstring.. cool,

Comment: Can we just do [myDictionary description] to get the dictionary in string format??

Answer (score 85):

Above Solutions will only convert dictionary into string but you can't convert back that string to dictionary.
For that it is the better way.

**Convert to String**

```
NSError * err;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:yourDictionary options:0 error:&err];
NSString * myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",myString);
```

**Convert Back to Dictionary**

```
NSError * err;
NSData *data =[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary * response;
if(data!=nil){
 response = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
}
```

Comment: It worked for single dictionary. What in case of multiple dictionaries ? I am unable to convert back to dictionary.

Comment: @VineetAshtekar see the title of this question.
Problem is conversion of NSDictionary to NSString.

Comment: @DanialHussain Yeah i know that. So? There can be arrays as values in dictionary right? So when it does, this method was not working.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `description` method inherited by `NSDictionary` from `NSObject`, or write a custom method that formats `NSDictionary` to your liking.

Comment: description method provides some extra info apart from the actual dictionary data.

Answer (score 2):

if you like to use for `URLRequest httpBody`

```
extension Dictionary {

    func toString() -> String? {
        return (self.compactMap({ (key, value) -> String in
            return "\(key)=\(value)"
        }) as Array).joined(separator: "&")
    }

}
```

// print:
Fields=sdad&ServiceId=1222